# SPARQL and DBPedia - getting the base url from a wiki page redirect name

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

My problem is simply this ... when I am querying with 'Barack', I am not getting the summary of 'Barack_Obama' dbpedia page. 
    I know what is the procedure of getting page redirect names from a base url name .

But , is the other way round possible ? Can I get 'Barack_Obama' by sending a query with 'Barack' ? Please help me with such SPARQL query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you want to start with the string "Barack" and then want to discover the URI that identifies Barack Obama, http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama.

This query does that:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?redirectsTo WHERE {
  ?x rdfs:label "Barack"@en .
  ?x dbo:wikiPageRedirects ?redirectsTo
}
```

Comment: @cygri it is not retrieving the whole list of redirect links why?